# How do I create a new array with an old array's keys as new array's values?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like:

```
Array
(
    [746] => 3
    [208] => 2
    [1091] => 1
    [313] => 1
    [305] => 1
    [707] => 1
)
```

I'd like to create an array like:

```
Array (
    [0] => 746
    [1] => 208
    [2] => 1091
    [3] => 313
    [4] => 305
    [5] => 707 )
```

I'm pretty sure I could do it with a foreach loop, but was wondering if there was an easier method available?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very easy with [array_keys](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

```
$newArray = array_keys($oldArray)
```

One advantage of use this built-in function instead of foreach is the power of C code compiled. So PHP native functions are, in general, more fast